# C char* array Value assignment index

Tags: c

While creating strjoin I noticed a strange phenomenon. When outputting a value strs in function strjoin()

These results were printed

```
123
```

Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char    *strjoin(int size, char **strs, char *sep)
{
    char *new;

    if (!(new = malloc(sizeof(char) * size)))
        return (NULL);

    printf("%s", strs[1]);
    return (NULL);
}

#include <unistd.h>

int     main(void)
{
    char* b[4] = {"123", "456", "789", "245"};
    char *p;
    int i = 0;
    int size = 5;
    char a[4] = {',', 'a', 'b', '\0'};

    p = *b;

    strjoin(5, &p, a);
}
```

Comment: `main()` should return integer as defined int.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` always equals to one then redundant.

Comment: Express exactly what do you want?

Comment: Your array has 4 elements, so I'm not sure why are you requesting 5 of them. "123" is shown twice because `p` is located after `b` on stack (hence, has lower address). You're passing address of `p`, but it is only 1 element, so indexes greater than 0 actually reference values from `b`, e.g. `strs[1]` is `b[0]`.

Comment: This code not compile. provide [mcve] version of program.

Comment: Presumably you want to call `ft_strjoin(4, b, a);`, note using `b` instead of `*p`.

Comment: @EsmaeelE, Since C99(?), the `return 0` can be omitted from `main`.

Comment: @ikegami explicit better than implecit. Never relay on specific version or compiler.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721336/7508077

Comment: @EsmaeelE, Poppycock. You can target C99 if you want to. (And it's over 20 years old now!) Furthermore, the linked post isn't relevant. I didn't say to change the declaration, only that the `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` is optional according to the C language, *even when declared as `int main(...)`*. (In fact, `main` must be declared to return `int` in C99.) Note that I didn't mention any compiler or version thereof.

Comment: @EsmaeelE, Did you actually read the answers to the question you linked? They say the same thing I did. Top answer: "*Whether `return 0;` should be omitted or not is open to debate.*" [The implication is that you *may* omit it.] Second answer: "*You may omit the return statement from `main()`.*"

Comment: The OP has written a function called `strjoin()` (which, BTW, does not join a pair of strings!)   Strongly suggest learning about `strcat()`

Comment: why allocate memory through the call to `malloc() and then 1) not use that allocated memory and 2) fail to pass that allocated memory to `free()` before exiting?

Comment: regarding: `char a[4]`  1) let the compiler count the number of elements.  2) since it is not used in the sub function, the third parameter to `strjoin()` can be eliminated AND the array `a[]` can be eliminated

Comment: the function: `strjoin()` returns a NULL pointer regardless of the success/fail of the call to `malloc()`  AND the call to `strjoin()` in `main()` does not check the returned value.  Suggest removing those `return NULL;` statements, change the returned type to `void` for the function `strjoin()`

Comment: @ikegami OK and thanks. You are correct. I check it as C99 its correct and `main()` without return statement will implicitly return 0; and not bad is happen from c99 to later standards.  But for completeness I'll check c89 this not happen and `main()` return non zero, for me 37. 
For c99 and earlier standards gcc -S put `movl    $0, %eax` in `main()` and I think this is what return for main. because changing it in .s file to `movl    $5, %eax` change return value to 5. I use `echo $?` to see return value. But For c89, `gcc -S -std=c89`  not add this command.

Comment: @hochan, The program your posted does not output what you claim is posted. Why did you change your answer to something incorrect again? I'm reverting the addition of the misinformation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order for it to be valid to use the value referenced by `str[1]`, `str` must point to an array of at least two `char*` elements. In your demonstration, it points to `p`, which is a single `char*`. Your program therefore invokes *Undefined Behaviour*, and thus your program is invalid.

It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps you wanted

```
char **p = &( b[0] );
strjoin(4, p, a)
```

Keep in mind that an array used where a pointer is expected degenerates into a pointer to its first elements, so the above is equivalent to the following:

```
char **p = b;
strjoin(4, p, a)
```

or simply

```
strjoin(4, b, a)
```

(The first parameter to `strjoin` isn't being used in your demonstration, but I imagine it's expected to be the number of elements in `*str`, so I have adjusted it the argument accordingly.)

Comment: Thank you very much I understand!

Comment: Excellent answer. Clarification No need to use extra double pointer to pointer `char **p`.

Comment: @EsmaeelE, Are you saying there's no reason to use `p`? The answer already demonstrates that.

Comment: "...an array used where a pointer is expected...." -- It might be helpful to be more explicit about this. Arrays decay to pointers to their first elements in _most_ expressions, the exceptions being when the array is an operand to the unary `&` address operator, or when the array is an operand to the `sizeof` operator, or when the array is a string literal used to initialize an array.